# <a> tag missing when rendered

Tags: php, html, xampp

This is the source code of the page. Im using XAMPP to host this.

```
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;gap: 1rem">
    <i class="uil uil-file-download-alt"></i>
    <div class="file-name">
        <a href="../../Handler/download.php?modMatID=<?php echo $id; ?>">Some file name.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eventually this is rendered:

```
<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;gap: 1rem">
    <i class="uil uil-file-download-alt"></i>
    <div class="file-name">Some file name.</div>
</div>
```

The anchor tag went missing when rendered. The `href` is 100% pointing to a valid dir that exist. This only happens at my end as all my group mates have no such issues. Wonder if this is any configuration issue with my PHP or XAMPP.

---------- UPDATE ----------

Tried using the private mode, disabling extensions, using different browsers and reinstalling XAMPP. Nothing works. Just realised that the rendered one is the old version from a few days ago. No matter how I edit the file it will still render the same old version.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but PHP won't usually display locally. That's the point of XAMPP though isn't it. Perhaps try a regular link first of all with no PHP in it... A test.

Comment: How are you looking at the "rendered" HTML? "View source code" or "developer tools inspector"? In this case you should be using the first, not the second.

Comment: _"This only happens at my end as all my group mates have no such issues."_ - with the _exact_ same code? Then maybe you have some browser extension running, that tries to filter out harmful stuff / privacy risks / malware ... Same problem when you view this in a private browsing window, without any extensions enabled?

Comment: @CuteCodeRob tried and not working. Another section in this code has a similar structure but it works... only these few lines are broken...

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes the first one

Comment: @CBroe  exact same code. Private mode is not working either.

Comment: Caching maybe? Has `<div class="file-name">Some file name.</div>` been the code at some time? Does anything change when you change the text in `<a href="../../Handler/download.php?modMatID=<?php echo $id; ?>">Some file name.</a>`? Have you tried disabling extensions as CBroe suggested? Did you try a different browser?

Comment: @brombeer yes at some time. Nothing changed even I changed the class `file-name` to something else. I tried disabling all extensions, also tried using private mode. Same. Chrome, firefox, edge and all the browser I have, still same =(

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the correct file? Try restarting XAMPP. Try CTRL-F5 reloading the source.  Your group mates not having this problem when viewing the page on _their_ XAMPP or on _yours_? Maybe compare XAMPP configurations from their PC versus yours.

Comment: @brombeer Pretty sure is the correct file. The problem is with my computer. Even tried to reinstall XAMPP and nothing works.